# 1172 - Result consisted of more than one row in mysql

Tags: mysql

How can I solve this problem (Result consisted of more than one row in `mysql`)

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `doMarksApplication`;
 CREATE PROCEDURE `doMarksApplication`(
 in  kuser varchar(20),
 out idpro int(11))
 SP:BEGIN
   declare no_more_rows  int  default FALSE;
   declare total_marks   decimal(10,2) default 0;
   declare idfor  int(11)       default 0; 
   declare sskod  int(5)        default getCurSession();
   declare bdata  int(5)        default 0;
   declare nopmh  varchar(20);
   # Data PB [Permohonan Baru] DM [Proses Pemarkahan] 
   declare cur1 cursor for
   select ind_nopmh from pinduk 
   left join pprses on pro_nopmh = ind_nopmh
   where ind_sskod = sskod and
   concat(pro_stats,pro_statp) in ('PB','DM') and
   not exists (select mar_idnum from pmrkah where mar_nopmh = ind_nopmh)
   order by ind_nopmh;
   declare continue handler for not found set no_more_rows = TRUE;

   begin
        select count(ind_nopmh) into bdata 
        from pinduk 
        left join pprses on pro_nopmh = ind_nopmh
        where ind_sskod = sskod and
              concat(pro_stats,pro_statp) in ('PB','DM') and
              not exists (select mar_idnum from pmrkah where mar_nopmh = ind_nopmh);
      end;

      begin
        select count(for_idnum) into idfor from xkod_markah_00_formula
        where for_stats = 'A' and
              curdate() between for_tkhdr and for_tkhhg;
      end;

      if idfor = 1 and sskod <> 0 then
        begin
          select for_idnum into idfor from xkod_markah_00_formula
          where for_stats = 'A' and
                curdate() between for_tkhdr and for_tkhhg;
        end;

        begin
          insert into pprmar
          (pma_tkmla,pma_msmla,pma_puser,pma_sskod,pma_idfor,pma_bdata)
          values
          (curdate(),curtime(),kuser,sskod,idfor,bdata);
        end;

        begin
          select last_insert_id() into idpro;
        end;

        open cur1;    
        LOOP1:loop    
          fetch cur1 into nopmh;

          if no_more_rows then
            close cur1;
            leave LOOP1;
          end if; 

          begin
            call getMarksAnakPerak(nopmh,@total_perak);
            call getMarksAkademik(nopmh,@total_akdmk);
            call getMarksSosioekonomi(nopmh,@total_sosio);
          end;

          set total_marks = @total_perak + @total_akdmk + @total_sosio;

          begin
            insert into pmrkah
            (mar_idpro,mar_nopmh,mar_idfor,mar_perak,mar_akdmk,mar_sosio,mar_total)
            values
            (idpro,nopmh,idfor,@total_perak,@total_akdmk,@total_sosio,total_marks);
          end;

          begin
            update pprses 
            set pro_stats = 'D',
                pro_statp = 'M',
                pro_tkmsk = curdate(),
                pro_msmsk = curtime(),
                pro_kuser = kuser
            where pro_nopmh = nopmh;
          end;

        end loop; 

        begin
          update pprmar
          set pma_tktmt = curdate(),
              pma_mstmt = curtime()
          where pma_idnum = idpro;
        end;
      end if;
 END;
```

Comment: Post your exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

i have been programming in mysql for 15 years and this is easily the most confusing stored procedure i have ever seen.

None the less, one possible place for your issue is here

```
select for_idnum into idfor from xkod_markah_00_formula
  where for_stats = 'A' and
        curdate() between for_tkhdr and for_tkhhg;
```

I know it does not seem to be the reason but without knowing the content of the other three stored procedures you are calling this is the only candidate. You should add a limit 1 to it, and to every select into statement that reads from a table (i.e. not a sum() or a count() etc...) as that would always have the potential to cause the error you are seeing.

```
select for_idnum into idfor from xkod_markah_00_formula
  where for_stats = 'A' and
        curdate() between for_tkhdr and for_tkhhg limit 1;
```

In addition, you should comment out the three stored procedure calls and see if the error goes away. My guess is that the issue is one of those stored procedures due to a select into similar to above has more than one row in the result set but does not use limit 1 and does not filter properly.